# Flash (ActionScript 3): how to build a remoting application

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, remoting

I'm looking for examples (code) of applications that uses Flash (NOT Flex) and Remoting classes for ActionScript 3 (NetConnection). Once there was ARP, a repository of code of this kind, but it seems there is not anymore. I'm trying to figure out how to build an applications that makes heavy use of calls to WebORB and responders. I need an architect point of view, NOT a sample of communication between parts, but a real world scenario.

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you to check out the [pimento / cinnamon](http://spicefactory.org/pimento/docs/1.1/manual/) documentation.